# Where is this table in Acumatica?

Tags: acumatica

I'm upgrading a customization that uses the following DAC:  'InventoryTranHistEnqResult'

The old customization used a field in this DAC (which I'm assuming was later removed) called InventoryID.
We're trying to find a substitute field, as the value of this field is used in an override of the 'resultRecords' view delegate.   Unfortunately, even though the DAC for this view exists and has the following designation, I can't find this table in SQL Server anywhere:

```
InventoryTranHistEnqResult : IBqlTable
```

The fields in this DAC are also prefixed with 'PXDB' - meaning, to me, that it's linked to a database field.

Where would I find InventoryTranHistEnqResult?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InventoryTranHistEnqResult DAC is in graph PX.Objects.IN.InventoryTranHistEnq

That graph is tied to an inquiry screen which doesn't have a Save action so the DAC isn't persisted to database.

I believe the InventoryID field you refer to was coming from the joins on INTran/INTranSplit used by the grid dataview.

```
[PXFilterable]
public PXSelectJoin<InventoryTranHistEnqResult,
    CrossJoin<INTran, CrossJoin<INTranSplit>>,
    Where<True, Equal<True>>> ResultRecords;
```